# Asp.net - Call Asp.Net function with Javascript result for parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-3.5

How can I call a Asp.Net function within parameter the result of a javascript function ?

Something like that :

```
var a = <%= MyFunction(getJs()) %>;
```

I know that something like that work :

```
var a = <%= MyFunction("test") %>;
```

Comment: You'll need to do a callback to the server with the result of your javascript function (if you want to process it on the server side that is). Look into implementing an AJAX call for this, JQuery makes it easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix server and client code.  `<%= %>` is executed on the server, and the javascript is executed on the client.

You should probably investigate another approach.  For example, depending on what your MyFunction() method does, consider porting it to your javascript.